# Ending Rec-Room game where if any player with 'fight' role dies the game ends?

Tags: rec-room

I'm trying to create a 1 vs 1 PVP where there's a 20 player capacity.  Any 2 players will enter a battlezone.  Once 2 players are in the battlezone, no one else will be able to enter.  Fighters fight until one dies.

Is it possible to create the logic, 'if any player with the 'fight' role has health =0, then end the game'? i'm trying to find a simple way to accomplish the goals above without tracking everyone's player id.

Answer (score 0):

Set both players to have a respawn point in a certain area. You can then remove their tag at that location with a trigger volume.

Periodically get the list of players with your desired tag and (assuming it will only be a 1v1) once that list's length is no longer 2, you can end the game.